Order of events in Shacharit vs Maariv: crossing the sea and drowning
In the morning prayer, in עֶזְרַת אֲבוֹתֵינוּ before the Amida we say:

מִמִּצְרַיִם גְּאַלְתָּנוּ, מִבֵּית עֲבָדִים פְּדִיתָנוּ, כָּל בְּכוֹרֵיהֶם הָרַגְתָּ, וּבְכוֹרְךָ גָּאַלְתָּ, וְיָם סוֹף בָּקַעְתָּ, וְזֵדִים טִבַּעְתָּ, וִידִידִים הֶעֱבַרְתָּ. וַיְכַסּוּ מַיִם צָרֵיהֶם אֶחָד מֵהֶם לֹא נוֹתַר. ‏

(Nussach Sefard is slightly different, but uses the same order)
Roughly translates to:

From Egypt You delivered us, from slavery You freed us, all the firstborns You killed, our firstborns You redeemed, the Yam Suf You split, the wicked ones You drowned, the beloved ones You passed through, their enemies drowned, not one was saved.

The bolded words are seemingly out of order: first we crossed the sea and then the Egyptians drowned.
In Arvit we say it in the correct order:

הַמַּכֶּה בְעֶבְרָתו כָּל בְּכוֹרֵי מִצְרָיִם, וַיּוֹצֵא אֶת עַמּוֹ יִשְׂרָאֵל מִתּוֹכָם לְחֵרוּת עוֹלָם, הַמַּעֲבִיר בָּנָיו בֵּין גִּזְרֵי יַם סוּף, אֶת רוֹדְפֵיהֶם וְאֶת שׂונְאֵיהֶם בִּתְהוֹמוֹת טִבַּע.‏


He smit in His anger the firstborn Egyptians, and delivered His nation Israel from them for everlasting freedom, He led His Sons between the split Yam Suf, their pursuers and enemies were drowned in its depths.

Why are the sequence of events in Shacharis in the wrong order?

The Etz Yosef commentary deals with this, starting on the fourth-last short line of this page.

@magicker72 nice midrash as an alternative.

This question was asked by Chasam Sofer on Torah, Seventh Day of Pesach:

זדים טבעת וידידים העברת ויכסו מים צריהם וכו' על זאת שבחו אהובים וכו' וכו' על שפת הים יחד כולם הודו והנה וזדים טבעת ואח"כ יאמר וידידי' העברת ובאמת אחר שהעביר ידידי' אח"כ ויכסו מים צריהם ולא קודם לכן גם לדקדק על זאת שבחו אהובי' וכו' ואח"כ אמר על שפת הים יחד כולם הודו וכו' מאי כולם דקאמר ונ"ל האי זדים לאו אנשים זדים היינו המצריים אלא זדים זדונות כמו מזדים חשוך עבדך ג"כ זדים זדונות עונות של ישראל הטבעת על דרך תשליך במצולות ים כל חטאתם וזה נגד מדה"ד שאמר מה נשתנו אלו מאלו הללו עע"ז והללו עע"ז והקב"ה השליך במצולות ים והטביע כל זדונות בזכות האמונה ואז ידידים העברת ויכסו מים צריהם ואז כשכיסו מים צריהם אז על זאת שבחו האהובי' והידידי' שבישראל ואמרו ההלל כדאי' פע"פ, אך שאר העם לא שבחו כי אמרו כשם שאנו עולים מצד זה כך מצרים עולים מצד אחר והמרו על ים בים סוף (כדאיתא פע"פ שם) עד שרמז הקב"ה ופלטם הים לחוץ כדכתי' וירא ישראל את מצרים מת על שפת הים וזו על שפת הים יחד כולם הודו שירת הים אפי' אותם שאינם אהובי ידידי' אלא כולם אמרו שירה:

As I understand, when comparing against the tefilas ma'ariv, it is important to note that Shacharis is the tefila of complete Geula, whereas Ma'ariv - only geula arichta (as discussed in Gemara Brachos). Therefore, in Ma'ariv we recall events briefly the way they occured, while in Shacharis we recite the full story.
Chasam Sofer states that the words וזדים טבעת - the wicked ones You drowned do not refer to the wicked men of Mitzraim, rather זדונות - wicked acts (willful sins) as it is stated in the passuk Tehilim 19:14

גַּ֤ם מִזֵּדִ֨ים ׀ חֲשֹׂ֬ךְ עַבְדֶּ֗ךָ אַֽל־יִמְשְׁלוּ־בִ֣י אָ֣ז אֵיתָ֑ם וְ֝נִקֵּ֗יתִי מִפֶּ֥שַֽׁע רָֽב׃
and from willful sins keep Your servant; let them not dominate me;
then shall I be blameless and clear of grave offense.

Also זדים - sinful acts (עונות) of Bnei Israel from the passuk Micha 7:19

יָשׁ֣וּב יְרַֽחֲמֵ֔נוּ יִכְבֹּ֖שׁ עֲוֺֽנֹתֵ֑ינוּ וְתַשְׁלִ֛יךְ בִּמְצֻל֥וֹת יָ֖ם כָּל־חַטֹּאותָֽם׃
[God] will take us back in love, Quashing our iniquities. You will hurl all our sins Into the depths of the sea.

According to midrash, these acts were performed against Midas haDin which spoke at the Yam Suf: Why are these different from those, these are idol worshipers and those are idol worshippers, and HKBH sent into the depths of the sea all the sinful acts (of Bnei Israel) in the merit of (their) Emunah and then the beloved ones You passed through; their enemies drowned, not one was saved. (There are different versions of the midrash, for example Yalkut Shimoni (Shemos), 234:6, Mekhilta R' Shimon b. Yochai 14:27).
